# Xcode with .cxx_construct

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I have a little problem with Xcode.
I import a header which contains this :

```
- (id).cxx_construct;
- (void).cxx_destruct;
```

so I try to set GCC_OBJC_CALL_CXX_CDTORS to yes in my build Settings on User-Defined !
But I still have this error :

```
Expected selector for Objective-C method
```

What can i do ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

these selectors are generated by the compiler. they are the reserved selectors for c++ ivar construction and destruction.

furthermore, the runtime calls these methods for you when `GCC_OBJC_CALL_CXX_CDTORS` is enabled. there is no need to call or declare them yourself.

declaring them would result in a compilation error.

> What can i do?

choose a unique name for your selectors, and don't implement the ones which are generated for you (when `GCC_OBJC_CALL_CXX_CDTORS` is enabled).

what is it you are trying to do here?

Comment: I try to compile header generated by class-dump, so all i have to do is remove my declaration of (id).cxx_construct thx ^^

Comment: @kavaliero ah, ok. the existence (and necessary removal) of the declaration makes sense in that context :)